# How to set min and max value in range input using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created a range slider using CSS and customized the as per my requirement. This is how it's looks like :

[image: Current range image]

```css
 .slidecontainer {
   width: 18%;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .slider {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   background: #dadadaa3;
   outline: none;
   opacity: 0.7;
   -webkit-transition: .2s;
   transition: opacity .2s;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }

 .slider:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 15px;
   height: 30px;
   background: #4CAF50;
   cursor: pointer;
   pointer-events:auto;
 }

 .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background: #4CAF50;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <span>10</span><input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="40" class="slider" id="myRange"><span>100</span>
</div>
```

But I need to set the Minimum value inside the beginning of the range and set the Maximum value inside the end of the range using CSS.

Comment: Why do you need it set using CSS? You have tagged the question JavaScript, why can it not be set using JavaScript?

Comment: can you clarify what do you need to do exactly ?

Comment: @cmprogram sorry that wash my mistake I updated my question and tag.

Comment: @YahyaEssam I have updated my question please check once for more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to give **.slidecontainer**

```
position:relative;
```

and set the **.min** and **.max** spans as

```
position:absolute;
```

```css
 .slidecontainer {
   width: 18%;
          position:relative;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .slider {
      
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   height: 30px;
   background: #dadadaa3;
   outline: none;
   opacity: 0.7;
   -webkit-transition: .2s;
   transition: opacity .2s;
   border-radius: 10px;
 }

 .slider:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 15px;
   height: 30px;
   background: #4CAF50;
   cursor: pointer;
   pointer-events:auto;
 }

 .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background: #4CAF50;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
        .min {
          position:absolute;
          left: 3px;
          top:8px;
        }
        .max {
         position:absolute;
         right: -12px;
         top: 8px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <span class="min">10</span><input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="40" class="slider" id="myRange"><span class="max">100</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 18%;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #dadada;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  position: relative;
}

.slider::before,
.slider::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}

.slider::before {
  right: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.slider::after {
  left: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <span>10</span><input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="10" class="slider" id="myRange"><span>100</span>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <span>10</span><input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="myRange"><span>100</span>
</div>
```